# Why does aws s3 bucketpolicy allow upload of objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this bucket policy( generated from policy generator).

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1620290934586",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1620290801219",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        },
        "Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy will allow objects to be uploaded only when there is sse-s3 header is present with aes256 value.
**Also i have enabled encryption settings for bucket wide using AWS KMS**.
so when i am trying to upload a file with default bucket encryption, according to policy it should not allow that because it doest not have sse-s3 header, yet file upload is successful? why?

i have followed [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/#:%7E:text=The%20policy%20needs%20to%20cover,server%2Dside%2Dencryption%20key.)

Update :-

the following policy works, means when i am using default bucket encryption settings during upload its denies. why didn't the above policy work and why the latter policy works?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjectPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnencryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` statement:

```
"Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
        }
```

can be [read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Null) as:

> if `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` **does not** exist.

Thus, if I understand correctly the IAM logic, the situation is as follows:

**First case**:

Your `Condition` reads as:

> if `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` does not exist **AND** is not equal to `AES256`.

Since you are using default encryption in the first try, there is no `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` key in the request. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html):

> A key that is **not present** in the request is considered a **mismatch**.

This means that your `Condition` is not satisfied and `Deny` does not apply.

**Second case**.

This one works, because by having two separate statements you are saying:

> if `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` does not exist **OR** is not equal to `AES256`

So `Deny` will take effect in any case.

Comment: i understood the logic but the first policy was generated by policy generator, how come i keep in mind to establish logical OR condition while creating a policy? is this some kind of bug in policy generator that it always generate policies in logical AND condition?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I'm not sure about policy generator, but there are other examples of OR with deny. Check the third policy in the examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-7).

Comment: Thank you marcin as always :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra No problem. Hope it helps. Just wish AWS made it clear how it all works, but I think that they also struggle to understand :-)

Comment: this is some kind of glitch with policy generator so upon adding contiion each time you need to explicitly add it and then add then add another condition otherwise it will result in a single statement,